# Go priority queues - assigning a sub-slice

Tags: go

I'm reading priority queues in the Go standard library [here](https://pkg.go.dev/container/heap) and I'm looking at this code

```
func (pq *PriorityQueue) Pop() interface{} {
    old := *pq
    n := len(old)
    item := old[n-1]
    old[n-1] = nil  // avoid memory leak
    item.index = -1 // for safety
    *pq = old[0 : n-1]
    return item
}
```

I'm somewhat concerned about this method of popping elements from a priority queue.. I know that a `PriorityQueue` type is a slice of pointers in that example and that a slice is a reference type so `old := *pq` only assigns the reference to the slice and doesn't actually copy anything, but what does the line `*pq = old[0 : n-1]` do? Does it create another slice or just copies a reference of the old slice with the begin-end indices set to `0` and `n-1`?

I'd like to use this class for a priority queue with potentially lots and lots of items and I'd like to avoid unnecessary copies.

Comment: Recommended reading, which should answer your question: https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro

Comment: There are no references in Go and neither are classes. If you are concerned about performance you should measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`old := *pq` makes a copy of whatever `pq` is pointing at.

Copying a slice makes a shallow copy - the copy is backed by the same array as the original slice.

`*pq = old[0 : n-1]` creates a new slice that is 1 element shorter and is backed by the same array.

Copying a slice is cheap, copying the backing array is expensive.

Mandatory read when working with slices: [Go Slices: usage and internals](https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro)